# DialogFlow I search how to jump an intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I search how to jump an intent, i have one topic with several context, i would like for my agent, he can give an answer to question 3 and get the context of the question 1 and 2, without ask the question 2, like this

[image: What_i_Want]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What isn't clear from your example is how you expect the conversation to "jump over" the second question. But keep this in mind:

Intents represent what the *user* says, and *not* how you reply.

Your fulfillment can handle input any way that makes sense at that moment and keep track of the state of your conversation. [Based on what the user says and the current state, you can reply and prompt for something else.](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/thinking-for-voice-design-conversations-not-logic-7c60869451f1)

If you have Input Context set for an Intent, that Intent will only be valid if *all* the Input Contexts are currently active. You can't have an Intent that will trigger if only one of them is.

The workaround for this is to have more than one Intent, each with the same training phrase, but with different Input Contexts. Then, in your fulfillment, you can either register the same Intent Handler for both, or have both Intent Handlers call the same function to actually do the work.

Comment: Thanx for you answer, i want get 2 contexts for one intent

Comment: Oh! Are you saying that you only want an Intent to trigger if both contexts are set?

Comment: I would like one intent with 2context and trigger if one it use

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you still need further clarification, I'd need to see what your current code looks like.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, it was what u thought !